# Changing primaryKeys order changes the order of the data saved in ROOM

Tags: android, android-room

I have a situation where I need some information about my results, in my code I have this data class/Room's entity.

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["searchId","page","pr_id"])
data class ProductResponse(
    var searchId: Int,
    val page: Int,
    @Embedded(prefix = "pr_")
    val products: ProductSearchFormatted
)
```

Where you can see in the Android Studios App Inspector:

[image]

The data is saved as spected in ROOM, when I try to load it from ROOM:

```
 @Query(
        "SELECT * FROM PagedSearchResponse WHERE searchId ==:input"
    )
    fun loadPagedSearchResponse(input: Int): PagingSource<Int, ProductResponse>
```

I just need the data in the same order that was previously saved, and got the data in different order (`ordered by pr_id`):

[image]

I found out that if I change the primaryKeys order, like

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["pr_id","searchId","page"])
data class ProductResponse(
    var searchId: Int,
    val page: Int,
    @Embedded(prefix = "pr_")
    val products: ProductSearchFormatted
)
```

Now the data's order from ROOM is correct.

Why does this happen? Does the primaryKeys order matter?

Answer (score 1):

> Changing primaryKeys order changes the order of the data saved in ROOM

NO it does not, the data is ALWAYS saved in the order in which it is inserted. What is changing in your case, is the ORDER in which the data is extracted. That is because you aren't saying in what ORDER you want the data to be extracted and are leaving that choice to the query planner.

> Why is this happened?, does the primaryKeys order matter?.

Yes it can do, especially in the absence of other indexes. Certainly **pr_id** before **search_id** will make a difference as the order within the index will be different and that as the **WHERE** clause is on the **search_id** then it is likely that the primary key index will be used (as in both cases **search_id** is an initial column *(see the links below)*)

- > The query planner is an AI that tries to pick the fastest and most efficient algorithm for each SQL statement.
- see :-

  - https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html
  - https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html
  - https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html

**If you want data to be in ORDER then you should specify an ORDER clause (`ORDER BY ....`). That is the only way to guarantee an ORDER.** Assuming an ORDER without an ORDER clause will very likely result in issues.

Saying that using pr_id prior to search_id makes the composite (multiplte column) index likely to be more beneficial as the pr_id (according to the data shown) is less repeated than the search_id.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer!, it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

The way I fix it, it was simpler than I expected.

In the entity, I added a field called "order", and in my Mediator (I'm using Paging 3) basically did this:

```
list.mapIndex { s,t ->
ProductResponse(
...
order = s
...
)
}
```

That way, I'm following the EXACT order from Backend without the need to modify any primaryKeys.